# Cannot create Android emulator for Android 4.03 (API Level 15)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have installed all the packages but the emulator for 4.0.3 (api level 15) in Android Studio (version 2.1) not appear. It is supported?

As you can see in the images, all is installed for api level 15.

[image: SDK packages for API 15]

[image: ARM]

[image: X86]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line!

**List All System Images Available For Download:**

`sdkmanager --list | grep system-images`

**Download System Image:**

`sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-15;default;x86"`

**Create the Emulator**

`echo "no" | avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name "NAME_OF_EMULATOR" --package "system-images;android-15;default;x86" --tag "default" --abi "x86"`

**Run the Emulator**

`emulator @NAME_OF_EMULATOR -skin 768x1280 &`

**Gist with more information:**

[Install and Create Emulators using AVDMANAGER and SDKMANAGER](https://gist.github.com/mrk-han/66ac1a724456cadf1c93f4218c6060ae)

[image: Emulator running 4.0.3]

Finally, add the following to `~/.android/avd/generic_10.avd/config.ini` to make sure it starts with an appropriate resolution and typing with your Laptop Keyboard is enabled. (This will make it so you don't have ot type -skin 768x1280 when starting the emulator.

```
skin.name=1080x1920
hw.lcd.density=480
hw.keyboard=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason android studio is showing you that recommendation message is that you have not selected system images that you have already installed in your computer

[image: here shows how selecting a system image already installed makes the error message disappear]

[here is a little more on adv and how to launch it from command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)